# Making GNU Make locate the correct library dependency

Tags: dependencies, makefile, gnu

I've got a simple Makefile in which one target depends on a library:

```
test49: test49.c -lpthread
```

The binary is built using the implicit rule for turning a .c file into an executable.

Problem is, I am trying to cross-compile, but make is interpreting `-lpthread` as pointing to `/usr/lib/libpthread.so`, which is quite incorrect.  I have defined the path to the cross-compiler using `CC=/path/to/bin/gcc`, so I would assume it could figure out that `-lpthread` should be somewhere in `/path/to/lib`, but it does not.

Comment: What's in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable?

Comment: How do you expect Make to guess `/path/to/lib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace

```
test49: test49.c -lpthread
```

with

```
test49: test49.c /path/to/lib/lpthread.so
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the workaround I came up with to, but having to hard-code it like that just seems wrong, and will cause more problems down the line.

Comment: You have to tell make where it is somehow. Telling make where gcc is doesn't tell it anything about the locations of `.so` files on your machine.

Comment: @Michael Is your libpthread in a non-standard location? You could also do as Dan seemed like he was about to suggest and append `/path/to/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is when multiple compilers are involved in a single build.  Having to explicitly specify a path means I now need a separate variable defined for every tool-chain and for every library that might be depended on.  Answer accepted, but for now I've just given up on the whole idea of make being able to accomplish this with minimal effort.